# how to clone html page when button cllick

Tags: html, clone, atag

how to clone html in new _blank page when i click

btn_change_folder_style_seg

btn_change_folder_style_raw

then content will be

```
<img src="./pic/web_show/3_seg/01.jpg" alt="">
<img src="./pic/web_show/3_seg/02.jpg" alt="">
```

and

```
<img src="./pic/web_show/3_raw/01.jpg" alt="">
<img src="./pic/web_show/3_raw/02.jpg" alt="">
```

now full code

```
<img src="./pic/web_show/3/01.jpg" alt="">
<img src="./pic/web_show/3/02.jpg" alt="">
<img src="./pic/web_show/3/03.jpg" alt="">

<input type="button" id="btn_change_folder_style_seg" value="style seg"></input>
<input type="button" id="btn_change_folder_style_raw" value="style raw"></input>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#btn_change_folder_style_seg').click(function() {
            alert("style_seg")
            var imagePath = $('img');
            imagePath.attr('src', function(index, attr) {
            if (attr) {
                return attr.replace('3/', index + 1 + '_seg/');
            }
            });
        });
        $('#btn_change_folder_style_raw').click(function() {
            alert("style_raw")
            var imagePath = $('img');
            imagePath.attr('src', function(index, attr) {
            if (attr) {
                return attr.replace('3/', index + 1 + '_raw/');
            }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "clone html page"? You can just open the same page in a new window / tab. Please clarify.

Comment: yes but new page content must change

Comment: Why change the page at all if most of it stays the same? And what has `atag` to do with this?

Comment: make a new html page and copy and paste the code and just change the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to select HTML tag and then make a copy of it through the cloneNode(true) method, you must add true to copy its children

then you can edit your cloned HTML as you want (delete elm - edit elm and so on)

therefore you gotta convert it to a string through (.outerHTML)

after that, you have to create a new instance of Blob Object and append the stringified content in it and add the type of your file

> const file = new Blob([content], {type: 'text/html'});

then you will need anchor tag to create the download link of you HTML file

> a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);

then trigger anchor tag to be clicked if you clicked the button tag

that's all I hope this snippet clarify my answer more

```js
// select button
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

// add click event
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Select anchor
    const a = document.getElementById('a');

    // select html tag
    const html = document.querySelector('html');
    // clone html
    const clonedHtml = html.cloneNode(true);

    // select elements
    const body = clonedHtml.querySelector('body');
    // wipe out body
    body.innerHTML = '';

    // create div
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    // add text
    div.innerText = 'new div';
    // append div
    body.append(div);

    //* append to content
    let content = `<!DOCTYPE html>`;
    content += clonedHtml.outerHTML;
    console.log(content);

    // create HTML file
    let file = new Blob([content], {
        type: 'text/html'
    });

    // add href link
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    // name file
    a.download = 'New.html';
    // run click
    a.click();

});
```

```html
<div class="div1">1</div>
<div class="div2">2</div>

<button type="button" id="btn">Generate HTML file</button>
<a id="a" href="" style="display: none;"></a>
```