# How do I create a text file using pure JavaScript, then append to it?

Tags: javascript

I want to append data into a txt file. I looked at other questions, and all of the answers were only supported in IE. This is what I have so far (I'm a complete JavaScript rookie, so I don't know anything about doing this kind of stuff):

var word = "word";
//Missing Code

What is the pure JavaScript code here????

Comment: Hi, please take a look to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51383975/615274

Comment: this answer might help you [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62191155/how-to-clone-html-page-when-button-cllick/62192400#62192400)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found old answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server)

```
const createTextFile = (fileNmae, text) => {
  const element = document.createElement('a');

  element.setAttribute(
    'href',
    'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text),
  );
  element.setAttribute('download', fileNmae);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
};

createTextFile('test.txt', 'word');
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. Is there another code snippet like this that works?

Comment: Its work successfully with me in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox

Comment: Can we give a path to download?

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = "some"
let file = new Blob([data], {type: "txt"})

// Appending to the file can be mimiced this way
data = data+"Text"
file = new Blob([data], {type: "txt"})

// To Download this file
let a = document.createElement("a"), url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
a.href = url;
a.download = file;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click()
setTimeout(function() {
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}, 0);
```

Hope this can help

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work. Any tips? I just pasted the code in the <script> in the HTML.